# Dropping a column based on the value of another pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to build and a method which takes a dataframe as input and returns the another dataframe as output after checking a certain condition.

If the `exception_type` column contains `FILE_REJECT`, it `drops` the `file_name` column, otherwise it does not.

I have provided various input and output to the method. Please help me build the method. Thank you.

```
Input
+------------+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+
|   file_name|register_number|jacket_number|annual_return_dt|data_type|exception_code|exception_type|
+------------+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+
|KKAR0523.ccn|       xxxxxxxx|     yyyyyyyy|      2001-12-22|      SHR|      CHAW0001|      SUSPENSE|
|KKAR0523.ccn|       xxxxxxxx|     yyyyyyyy|      2001-12-22|      SHR|      CHAR0006|    REC_REJECT|
|KKAR0523.ccn|       xxxxxxxx|     yyyyyyyy|      2001-12-22|      SHR|              |              |
+------------+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+

+------------+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+
|   file_name|register_number|jacket_number|annual_return_dt|data_type|exception_code|exception_type|
+------------+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+
|KKAR0523.ccn|       zzzzzzzz|     yyyyyyyy|      2001-12-22|      SHR|              |              |
|KKAR0523.ccn|       zzzzzzzz|     yyyyyyyy|      2001-12-22|      SHR|      CHAR0001|   FILE_REJECT|
+------------+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+

+------------+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+
|   file_name|register_number|jacket_number|annual_return_dt|data_type|exception_code|exception_type|
+------------+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+
|KKAR0523.ccn|       xxxxxxxx|     yyyyyyyy|      2001-12-22|      SHR|      CHAR0002|   FILE_REJECT|
|KKAR0523.ccn|       xxxxxxxx|     yyyyyyyy|      2001-12-22|      SHR|      CHAR0001|   FILE_REJECT|
+------------+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+
```

```
Output
+------------+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+
|   file_name|register_number|jacket_number|annual_return_dt|data_type|exception_code|exception_type|
+------------+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+
|KKAR0523.ccn|       xxxxxxxx|     yyyyyyyy|      2001-12-22|      SHR|      CHAW0001|      SUSPENSE|
|KKAR0523.ccn|       xxxxxxxx|     yyyyyyyy|      2001-12-22|      SHR|      CHAR0006|    REC_REJECT|
|KKAR0523.ccn|       xxxxxxxx|     yyyyyyyy|      2001-12-22|      SHR|              |              |
+------------+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+

+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+
|register_number|jacket_number|annual_return_dt|data_type|exception_code|exception_type|
+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+
|       zzzzzzzz|     yyyyyyyy|      2001-12-22|      SHR|              |              |
|       zzzzzzzz|     yyyyyyyy|      2001-12-22|      SHR|      CHAR0001|   FILE_REJECT|
+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+

+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+
|register_number|jacket_number|annual_return_dt|data_type|exception_code|exception_type|
+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+
|       xxxxxxxx|     yyyyyyyy|      2001-12-22|      SHR|      CHAR0002|   FILE_REJECT|
|       xxxxxxxx|     yyyyyyyy|      2001-12-22|      SHR|      CHAR0001|   FILE_REJECT|
+---------------+-------------+----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please share what code did you try so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using such method:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

def process_dataframe(input_df):
    if 'file_name' in input_df.columns and 'exception_type' in input_df.columns:
        if input_df.filter(col('exception_type') == 'FILE_REJECT').count() > 0:
            output_df = input_df.drop('file_name')
        else:
            output_df = input_df
    else:
        output_df = input_df
    
    return output_df
```

BR